# Is it possible to write every function as "pure function" in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, ecmascript-6, functional-programming, pure-function

I am interested in **functional programming**, so I decided to try this approach on the scripting environment of my **Google Sheets** file, and you know that the scripting language is **Google Apps Script**, which is basically **javascript**. And it even supports some (if not all) ES6 syntax.

The problem is that I cannot directly run any code, for example:

```
let a = 4;
Logger.log(a);
```

I mean, I cannot run it globally, I need to define a function with any name, and then place the code inside that function, and I can run the function, so the function runs the code inside.

So, maybe you ask, "why this behavior makes a problem writing pure functional code?" well, because, as I know, two of the most important factors about pure functions are:

**1) We must not use global variables/functions inside a function, instead we must pass as parameters (and then as arguments of course).**

**2) defining function inside a function is often not very good idea in terms of readability and organization of the code.**

So, I want to define more functions (to do some stuff), not just one "main" function, and I could not find any way, any single way to write code (as a whole) without violating at least one of the two statements above.

So, I mean, I can not write anything without making at least one non-pure function.

Comment: If you ever want to be able to *do* something useful with the code (eg, log a message, change a cell, etc), you won't be able to write in a purely functional way. Side-effects are required at least in *certain points* for a script to be able to accomplish anything.

Comment: *2) defining function inside a function is often not very good idea in terms of readability and organization of the code.* Not at all, this is quite common, and often nearly essential, at least in Javascript.

Comment: In FP you can use Monads to model effects. Effects and side-effects are different things. You can find plenty of material in the internet about Monads and Effects.

Comment: Your 1st assumption is partially incorrect. A function must not depend on globale, mutable variables, but it may depend on global constants and global pure functions. However, often you rather want to pass a function dependency as an argument to obtain a more general higher order function. Your 2nd assumption is merely opinion based.

Comment: Your second assumption violates principle of least access. The function doesn't need to be globally accessible, if you use it only inside one function

Answer (score 0):

As a user explained in the comments:

Your 1st assumption is partially incorrect. A function must not depend on global, mutable variables, but it may depend on global constants and global pure functions. However, often you rather want to pass a function dependency as an argument to obtain a more general higher order function. Your 2nd assumption is merely opinion based.

So you could, for example, define a main function to run your code as a whole while defining functions inside the main function to achieve functional programming with Apps Script.

Comment: I think I have found the solution. I can use default parameters for functions, so the functions will grab another function as arguments, and not with global call.

For example:
`
function dog() {
    return 4;
}

function readDog(d = dog) {
    Logger.log(d());
}
`